# Why can I start a root shell with sudo even with a '! ' in its shadow entry?

Tags: permissions, sudo, passwd, shadow

```
$cat /etc/passwd |grep -i root
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash

$sudo cat /etc/shadow |grep -i root
root:!:17179:0:99999:7:::
```

In the second field of shadow file, `!` means root user cannot login but why can I login to root user by `sudo su`?

Why can't I  login to root user by `su root` or `su -`?

Comment: _"In the second field of shadow file, ! means root user cannot login"_ No, it doesn't. Where did you hear that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, what does it mean?

Comment: @George: muru quoted the manual in his answer and explained it in detail. You should read documentation!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An `!` in the `shadow` entry's encrypted password field means that no password can authenticate against it. From [`man shadow`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/shadow.5.html):

```
If the password field contains some string that is not a valid
result of crypt(3), for instance ! or *, the user will not be able
to use a unix password to log in (but the user may log in the
system by other means).
```

As the manual says, this *does not* mean that you can't login as root. It just means that you can't login as root using a password for the root account. (You can login as root via SSH using SSH keys, for example, if you had configured it earlier, even if the account is locked.)

`sudo` normally authenticates with *your* password, not root's. This can be changed by setting one of `targetpw`, `rootpw` or `runaspw` in `sudoers`. If you set one these options, and try to use a password when the password is locked, **that will fail**.

Comment: Great, it means i can switch to any user by sudo with my password either it is active user or lock user,right?

Comment: @Sinoosh assuming no other restrictions, yes

Answer (score 4):

Now let's look at the commands accordingly:

1. `sudo su`:

   - `sudo` runs the command `su` (substitute user) with root privileges so even if the `/etc/shadow` says or has `root:!:17179:0:99999:7:::` it will still run commands with root privileges.
2. `su -` or `su root`:

   - This actually *switches* to the *root user* which from the `/etc/shadow` file can not log in so using these commands will not work. If you want them to work then the *root account* must be unlocked by giving it a password.

Summary:

`su -` 0r `su root` switches to user *root*, does not exist so it can't happen, but `sudo su` runs *switch command* with `root` privileges, so in this case it will go if you are in the `sudo` group. You're not actually logging in as root in this case, just acting as *root* so it will go.

Source: [What is the difference between 'su -' and 'su root'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15611)

Comment: Thank you, It means `sudo su` does not see pass fields in shadow file?

Comment: @Sinoosh `sudo su` is the wrong way to run `sudo sh` or `sudo bash`.